# Creating an evenly spaced array of double precision values

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, double

I'm a noob in C and I come from Matlab. I'm going crazy to do a very simple operation like creating an array of evenly spaced numbers.
What I want to do is have an array of 50 elements, starting from 0 with a constant increment of 0.1.
In matlab it would be as simple as:

```
n=50;
h=0.1;
t=0:h:(n-1)*h;
```

In C I am trying this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int n = 50;    
  double h = 0.1;

  double t[n];
  t[0] = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    t[i+1] = t[i] + h;
    printf("%i %d\n",i, t[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is something crazy like:

```
0 0
1 -1717986918
2 -1717986918
3 858993460
4 -1717986918
5 0
6 858993459
7 1717986918
8 -1717986919
9 -858993460
10 -1
...
```

And I really can't understand why.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `printf("%i %d\n",i, t[i])`, `t[i]` is a `double`, but `%d` requires that you pass an `int`. Use `%g` for a general format for printing `double`.

Comment: Of course. Thanks! I somewhat assumed that the "d" in %d stands for "double"... I should learn to never assume something in C.